# Problems with GoogleVisualization API for JavaScript - Get data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I'm using the Google Visualization API with JavaScript to show a data table. The problem is: I can show the data if I create a variable with the required content, but when I get the same data from AJAX I can´t build the table.

Here is the code that works:

```
    function mostrarCuadro() {
          var datos = [["Nombre","Altura","Apariencia","Blablabla","Cualidad","Presencia","Puntualidad","Talento"],["L L",0,3,0,2,4,3,0],["M B",0,3,0,4,5,2,0],["S L",2,2,3,3,3,4,2]];
          datos = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datos);
          // Create and draw the visualization.
          visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
          visualization.draw(datos, null);
        }
```

In the other case (which won't work), I get the data from MySQL using an AJAX jQuery using a PHP file as the server-side:

```
function obtenerData(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="Cargando...";
    $(function () 
    {
        $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'obtieneCuadro.php',           //the script to call to get data          
        data: "id=22755",                   //url argumnets
        dataType: 'html',                   //data format      
        success: function(data)         //on recieve of reply
        {
        var recibido = data;
        datos = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(recibido);
          // Create and draw the visualization.
          visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
          visualization.draw(datos, null);
        } 
        });
    }); 
}
```

My PHP file returns (I get that in the variable 'recibido'):

```
[["Nombre","Altura","Apariencia","Blablabla","Cualidad","Presencia","Puntualidad","Talento"],["L L",0,3,0,2,4,3,0],["M B",0,3,0,4,5,2,0],["S L",2,2,3,3,3,4,2]]
```

As you can see, the two variables has the same content, but in the second case it won't work. Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how can I make it work?

Thank you.

---

EDIT:
I've managed to solve the problem, now it's working fine... I show here the correct code that is working right now:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function obtenerData(){
  document.getElementById("table_div").innerHTML="Cargando...";
  $(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'obtieneCuadro.php',         //the script to call to get data          
      data: "id=22755",                 //url argumnets
      dataType: 'html',                 //data format      
      success: function mostrarCuadro(data)         //on recieve of reply
      {
          datosTabla = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(data));
          // Create and draw the visualization.
          visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
          visualization.draw(datosTabla, null);
      } 
    });
  }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: leiboleo, if you add your edit as an answer, you can mark this question as answered which will be nicer (it will look solved).

Comment: I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem, now it's working fine... I leave here the correct code that is working right now:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function obtenerData(){
  document.getElementById("table_div").innerHTML="Cargando...";
  $(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'obtieneCuadro.php',         //the script to call to get data          
      data: "id=22755",                 //url argumnets
      dataType: 'html',                 //data format      
      success: function mostrarCuadro(data)         //on recieve of reply
      {
          datosTabla = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(data));
          // Create and draw the visualization.
          visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
          visualization.draw(datosTabla, null);
      } 
    });
  }); 
}
</script>
```

I had to parse the data with "JSON.parse(data)".